# Can I use a custom class as an api endpoint body input

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am setting up a api endpoint with swagger and need the body class to be same as the swagger model class but doing this stops the endpoint from working.

```
@Operation(description = "body example is in model tab", 
responses = {@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = 
"description") }, summary = "summary", tags = "Courier APIs")
@POST
@Secured
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response foo(
        @RequestBody(required = true, content = 
        @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = SwaggerMessages.class),
         mediaType = "application/xml")) SwaggerMessages body) {

    //do work with body
}
```

I would like to be able to send some encoding of the class (i.e. xml of json)as the resquest body, but when i tried sending a request to that endpoint it always returns error 500 without even getting in the method

Comment: if you get 500 you should see an exception in the logs, what does it say?

Comment: the only thing that gets logged is this :
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [04/Nov/2019:13:33:05 -0500]
 "POST /SMSGateway/api/test HTTP/1.1" 500 1081
I think it might because it doesnt know whow to map the request body to the SwaggerMessages object